# Show mappings for all function keys

Tags: key-bindings

How can I show the mappings for all function keys `<F1>` to `<F12>` at once? I know that `:map <F1>` shows the mapping for `<F1>`, and I can repeat this 12 times for each key. But is there a faster way?  I have tried `:map <F` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this with a loop:

```
for i in range(1, 12) | execute 'map <F'.i.'>' | endfor
```

If you don't want any output for F-keys without mappings, you can use `mapcheck()`, as [suggested by @BLayer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20192/show-mappings-for-all-function-keys/20193#comment35358_20193):

```
for i in range(1, 12) | if !empty(mapcheck('<F'.i.'>')) | execute 'map <F'.i.'>' | endif | endfor
```

For more details, see:

- `:help :for`
- `:help :execute`
- `:help range()`
- `:help mapcheck()`

Comment: For cleaner output, omitting non-mapped "F" keys,  the `execute` expression could be expanded to `'if mapcheck("<F'.i.'>") != "" | map <F'.i.'> | endif'`

Comment: Thanks for the clean and simple solution. Initially, I had thought of using regex (and later, with `:filter`), but it seems that a loop is better suited for this situation.

Answer (score 6):

The [:filter](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Afilter) allows to filter the output of certain vim commands. Currently, this is not yet supported by every Vim command, but according to [:h map-listing](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#map-listing), it should be possible. As the help states:

```
The :filter command can be used to select what mappings to list.  The
pattern is matched against the {lhs} and {rhs} in the raw form.
```

This means, you would need to put up a custom filter command with the **raw** key codes as input to the filter command. I was able to come up with this somewhat convoluted example for all `<f>` keys:

```
exe ":filter" join(map(range(1,12), { i,v -> eval('"\<f'.v.'>"')}), '\|') ":map"
```

This creates a list of each raw `<f>` key by using the `"\<f1>"` form (which will then be parsed into the correct raw key code by vim (therefore, the `eval()` is needed). The resulting list, is then joined together into a regular expression, with each item joined by the `\|` regex atom (OR).

As the help states, the filter criteria will be applied to both, the left and right side of a mapping, so if the criteria matches the right side, it will be output as well.

Note, in order to really get all mapping output, you might as well need the `:map!` command to get insert and commandline mappings.

Overall this is a lot more complicated than to use the solution provided by [Rich](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/20193/71)

Comment: Is it possible to do something such as `:filter /raw code of <f3>/ map`  without using `exec`?

Comment: I don't think so, since one needs the special `"\<key>"` notation

Comment: I guess you are right. If the raw code sequence starts with 0x80,  one have to use the special "\<key>" notation.

Comment: Thanks, `:filter` was what I was looking for. I managed to grasp the main gist behind your example but it will take me some time before I fully understand it. Also, can the example be simplified to something along the lines of `"\<f".'\d\{1,2\}'.">"`?

Comment: @husB no, because as I said, the filter works on the raw key codes.